# Example of a vector space $V$ which is a linear map $f: V\to V$, so that $f$ is injective but not an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a vector space $V$ which is a linear map $f: V\to V$, so that $f$ is injective but not an isomorphism.

Linear map: $f:V\to V$ such that $f(av+bw)=af(v)+bf(w), \forall v,w \in V, \forall a,b \in K$

injective: $f(v)=f(w)\implies v=w$

isomorphism: bijective homomorphism

I wanted to try to show a surjection, but I cant with the linear map going from $V \to  V$

Comment: For $V$ the set of infinite sequences, map $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$ to $(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$.

Comment: but doesn't $V \to V$ mean they have to have the same elements, this example would not hold since $0$ would not be in the domain

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the zero vector above is $(0,0,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), you need $V$ to be infinite dimensional for that. For instance, if $V$ has a countable basis $v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots$, just let $f$ map $v_{i}$ to $v_{i+1}$.